# Multithreading during image build

Tags: java, maven, docker

I'm building a custom image that contains my java app.
Basically I'm calling `mvn clean install` inside the `Dockerfile`.
I'm using this `RUN mvn -T 1C clean install` in order to speed up the process.

This will use 1 thread per available CPU core. Will this be enough? How does mvn calculate the available cpu cores? Do I have to do something in order to tell it to check the host's CPUs and not the VM's? I'm using Docker for Mac (which internally uses xhyve as far as I know).

Update:

I'm building one module (fat jar, spring boot application with tomcat embedded), maven 3.3.9, about 30 mins of total duration without the thread boost. The huge overhead is that it downloads dependencies from my private repo in S3.

Comment: Docker for Mac is a virtual machine (boot2docker) runs on on VirtualBox. I think you could open the VirtualBox and re-config the boot2docker VM.

Comment: First how many modules are you building? How long does the build take without `-T..`? Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @Tuan https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/ `Docker for Mac is our newest offering for the Mac. It runs as a native Mac application and uses xhyve to virtualize the Docker Engine environment and Linux kernel-specific features for the Docker daemon.`

Comment: @khmarbaise One module (fat jar, spring boot application), maven 3.3.9, about 30 mins. The huge overhead is that it downloads dependencies from my private repo in S3.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#/preferences You could edit CPU here.

Comment: @Tuan I've already done that. Will the Dockerfile build process utilise what I have configured? Can I print the number of threads used by maven?

Comment: I've not checked it yet. But I think it's possible. ```CPUs - By default, Docker for Mac is set to use 2 processors. You can increase processing power for the app by setting this to a higher number, or lower it to have Docker for Mac use fewer computing resources.```

Comment: If you have only a single module the option `-T ..` will not increase the build performance. The download from s3 should be proxied / cached by a repository manager that will improve your build performance...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you for your help. Please provide your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my humble opinion I think that build application by maven inside Dockerfile get more issues than benefits.

When you run new  build maven cache is empty so your build spend many time to download all dependencis.

Changing threds used by build do not give you any performance boost.

You can try prepare one docker image with maven and try run some maven command to populate maven cache in this image build.
Next you use this image as base for your project.

Another solution maybe separate download dependency and build in two RUN, thanks docker cache your next build may be faster.

```
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline
RUN mvn clean install
```